# Why does itemClicked() function not work sometimes in ionic2 / angular2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**The problem**

A very common problem of the Angular (click) functionality is that when you're using `<div>` tags, then it may not work.

In some cases you will need to click two or three times.

I had the same issue myself, after researching a lot I found the solution:

Just exchange `<div>` tags with `<buttton>` tags.

My previous code:

```
<div class="some-outer-class">
      <div class="some-inner-class" (click)="itemclicked($event, someId)">
              Explore
      </div>
</div>
```

It is now with the `<button>` tag.

```
<div class="explore-outer-container">
     <button class="explore-rotate-text" (click)="itemclicked($event, someId)">
          Explore
      </button>
</div>
```

**Note: both `<div>` and `<span>` do not work well.**

*Hope it will help you too.*

Some other sources-

1. [ionic framwork](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/click-in-list-item-in-simulator-sometimes-doesnt-work-in-button-or-browser-it-does/54990)
2. [Blog](https://randvblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/14/why-does-click-function-not-work-sometimes-in-ionic-angular/)

Comment: Can you provide us with your `itemClicked()` method? Because this might be a different problem than the `(click)` event

Comment: is it sounds good now?. @Ivaro18.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the plunkr? https://plnkr.co/edit/pLN45f0KU7UM3sc94d4Y?p=preview

Comment: Are you (in your `itemClicked` method, using the `navController.push() `method?

Comment: If you observe @rinukkusu, 
I have mention issue and its solution also.

Comment: Oh, then add it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ionic currently has a bug relating it's `navCtrl.push()` method and using a `selector: your-selector` tag on the page you're pushing to.

This will cause the page to reload itself when you click the first time but loads good after you click the `div` for the second time, which would explain your problem of having to click twice.

But because I do not know what your `itemClicked()` is executing, I couldn't say for sure.

(If this is your problem see: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7979#issuecomment-244882983 which was my own issue)